# How to fix / handle OpenCV crash in Calib3d.findChessboardCorners method Android

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I am implementing camera calibration using OpenCV from a list of images. When implementing this I am using the following code to find whether the chessboard pattern is found or not. It works sometimes, and also crashes some times in the **Calib3d.findChessboardCorners** method.

```
Mat bgrImage = Imgcodecs.imread(file.toString());

//Creating Gray Scale Image
Mat grayImage = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

//Find pattern
MatOfPoint2f corners = new MatOfPoint2f();
boolean isPatternFound = Calib3d.findChessboardCorners(grayImage, mPatternSize, corners, Calib3d.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
```

Crash Log

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7f6d600000 in tid 22936 (AsyncTask #2)
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG: pid: 22825, tid: 22936, name: AsyncTask #2  >>> com.trimble.javacamera2viewcalibration <<<
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7f6d600000
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000004  x1   0000000000000002  x2   00000000ffffffff  x3   0000000000000001
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     x4   00000000000000bc  x5   0000007f832bc130  x6   0000008f00000399  x7   0000008e000003a2
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000007f6d5ffff8  x9   0000000000000003  x10  0000000000000002  x11  0000007f6d5ffff8
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000003  x13  0000000000000001  x14  0000000000000004  x15  0000000000000002
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007f74752c08  x17  0000007f738e80f8  x18  00000000000003a2  x19  0000007f6d7f3e70
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000007f6d7f3d40  x21  0000007f6d7f8588  x22  0000007f6d7f3e50  x23  0000000000000018
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000591  x25  0000000000000030  x26  000000008203000c  x27  0000000000000c02
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000007f6d7f3ee8  x29  0000007f6d7f3d20  x30  0000007f73b9f02c
2019-08-05 11:02:01.121 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f6d7f3ce0  pc   0000007f73b9f1a0  pstate 0000000080000000
2019-08-05 11:02:01.124 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-08-05 11:02:01.124 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000005cd1a0  /data/app/com.trimble.javacamera2viewcalibration-vW4SZ1V7iwFtfU5fjL7JVg==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so
2019-08-05 11:02:01.125 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000005ccb3c  /data/app/com.trimble.javacamera2viewcalibration-vW4SZ1V7iwFtfU5fjL7JVg==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so (_ZN2cv12boundingRectERKNS_11_InputArrayE+252)
2019-08-05 11:02:01.125 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000000000092d664  /data/app/com.trimble.javacamera2viewcalibration-vW4SZ1V7iwFtfU5fjL7JVg==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so
2019-08-05 11:02:01.125 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000000000092bc04  /data/app/com.trimble.javacamera2viewcalibration-vW4SZ1V7iwFtfU5fjL7JVg==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so (_ZN2cv21findChessboardCornersERKNS_11_InputArrayENS_5Size_IiEERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+3368)
2019-08-05 11:02:01.125 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0000000000209ad4  /data/app/com.trimble.javacamera2viewcalibration-vW4SZ1V7iwFtfU5fjL7JVg==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so (Java_org_opencv_calib3d_Calib3d_findChessboardCorners_10+108)
2019-08-05 11:02:01.125 22954-22954/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0000000000011d88  /data/app/com.trimble.javacamera2viewcalibration-vW4SZ1V7iwFtfU5fjL7JVg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0xc000)
```

Comment: see also http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/OpenCV#SIGILL_when_calling_findChessBoardCorners_on_MacOS_10.13.6_with_macports_opencv